# use pinia outside of component raises no active pinia error

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, vite, pinia

I'm working on a Vue.js 3 project build using [ViteSse](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse) template, I wanna use one of my Pinia stores named notificationStore outside of the setup component but I get `getActivePinia called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install Pinia` error when I ran the dev command Its behavior is so strange because it does not occur if I add useNotificationStore after the dev server loaded and It works well but when useNotificationStore exists in my ts file and run dev command it raise error.

[image: console error]

http-client.ts:

```js
import type { AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios'
import axios from 'axios'
import tokenService from './token.service'
import { useNotificationsStore } from '~/store/notification.store'
const notification = useNotificationsStore()
const httpClient: AxiosInstance
  = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_URL}/`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })


httpClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    if (response.config.method !== 'get') {
      const successMsg = 'operation successfully completed'
      notification.addNotification({ type: 'success', message: successMsg })
    }
    return response
  },
  (error) => {
    if (error.message === 'Network Error') {
      notification.addNotification({ type: 'error', message: 'Network Error' })
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
    let errorMessage = ''
    const validationErrors = getValidationErrors(error)
    errorMessage = getErrorMessage(error)
    notification.addNotification({ type: 'error', message: errorMessage, validationErrors, hideAfterRouting: false })
  }
)
```

I have traced the issue with some logging and found that it occurred before createApp was executed that initiated Pinia and there was no active Pinia at that time. I expected createApp in main.ts to have been executed before all

thanks in advance

Comment: Reading long questions like this is very hard! Please try to ask your question more summarized.

Comment: You are right, I have removed redundant and non-related codes. @SVG-Heart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by reading [documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html#single-page-applications) carefully:

> The easiest way to ensure this is always applied is to defer calls of useStore() by placing them inside functions that will always run after pinia is installed.

I just update http-client by removing useNotificationStore() from the top of the file and where I need notificaitonStore instance use useNotificationStore().addNotification(...)

```js
import type { AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios'
import axios from 'axios'
import tokenService from './token.service'

const httpClient: AxiosInstance
  = axios.create({
    baseURL: `${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_URL}/`,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })

httpClient.interceptors.request.use(
  (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
    const token = tokenService.getLocalAccessToken()
    if (token && config.headers)
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`

    return config
  },
  (error) => {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  },
)
httpClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    if (response.config.method !== 'get') {
      const successMsg = 'operation successfully completed'
       useNotificationsStore().addNotification({ type: 'success', message: successMsg })
    }
    return response
  },
  (error) => {
    if (error.message === 'Network Error') {
       useNotificationsStore().addNotification({ type: 'error', message: 'Network Error' })
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
    let errorMessage = ''
    const validationErrors = getValidationErrors(error)
    errorMessage = getErrorMessage(error)
    useNotificationsStore().addNotification({ type: 'error', message: errorMessage, validationErrors, hideAfterRouting: false })
  }
)
```

Comment: There's an easier way: in `@/store/index.ts` do `export const pinia = createPinia()`. And place `import { pinia } from '@/store'` at the top of the imports in `main.ts`. This ensures `createPinia()` gets called before anything else in your app is run and an active pinia has already been created in the context.

Comment: I don't mean to be disrespectful, but when the car breaks down the only acceptable solution is *"Fixed the car and drove to destination"*. *"I walked the rest of the way"* doesn't really qualify, does it?

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you have not registered pinia with the app

```
export const createApp = ViteSSG(
  App,
  { routes, base: import.meta.env.BASE_URL },
  async (ctx) => {
    Object.values(import.meta.glob<{ install: UserModule }>('./modules/*.ts', { eager: true }))
      .forEach(i => {
        i.install?.(ctx)
      })

// install pinia 
    const pinia = createPinia()
    ctx.app.use(pinia)

    if (import.meta.env.SSR)
      ctx.initialState.pinia = pinia.state.value
    else
      pinia.state.value = ctx.initialState.pinia || {}
// ============

    const DEFAULT_TITLE = 'Dashboard'
    ctx.router.beforeEach((to) => {
// ====== use store ====
      const { state } = useOidcStore()

      if (!store.ready)
        // perform the (user-implemented) store action to fill the store's state
        store.initialize()
// ===========
      if (!state.value.user) {
        autoAuthenticate()
      }
      let title = DEFAULT_TITLE
      if (to.meta.title)
        title = `${to.meta.title} - ${title}`

      document.title = title
    })
  },
)
```

> Please remove useOidcStore() on top level

Comment: due to vitesse default configuration pinia is installing using pinia.ts config file inside modules folder and it works perfectly inside .vue files but not inside .ts files

Comment: the problem is not there the problem is that you are asking for `useOidStore` while pinia is not installed yet

Comment: I moved useOidcStore after installing pinia and the problem doesn't solve, I attach console error image to the question, error raises from line 4 of http-client.ts and when I comment out useNotificaitionStore inside it, the app fires up